# Mobile list item pressed and longtap event

Tags: mobile, qooxdoo

In this little qooxdo mobile example I need know the list item pressed when longtap is triggered. How I can know?

```
var page = new qx.ui.mobile.page.NavigationPage();
page.setTitle("List");
page.addListener("initialize", function() {
  var list = new qx.ui.mobile.list.List({
    configureItem : function(item, data, row) {
      item.setTitle(data.title);
      item.setSubtitle(data.subTitle);
      item.setSelectable(true);
      item.setShowArrow(true);
    }
  });

  var data = [];
  for (var i=0; i < 50; i++) {
    data.push({title:"Item" + i, subTitle:"Subtitle for Item #" + i});
  }

  list.setModel(new qx.data.Array(data));
  list.addListener("changeSelection", function(evt) {
    alert("Item Selected #" + evt.getData());
  }, this);

  list.addListener("longtap", function(evt) {

      // <--- HERE I NEED KNOW THE LIST ITEM PRESSED

  }, this);

  page.getContent().add(list);
},this);

this.getManager().addDetail(page);

page.show();
```

please I need some help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

a solution:

```
list.addListener("longtap", function(evt) {
    var originalTarget = evt.getOriginalTarget();
    while (originalTarget.tagName != "LI") {
        originalTarget = originalTarget.parentNode;
    }

    var itemIndex = parseInt(originalTarget.getAttribute("data-row"), 10);
    alert("Item Selected #" + itemIndex);
});
```